# How to create а column with division name for first sale via postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

| user_id | company | division_name | sale | sale_date | fist_division_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | red | name 1 | 100 | 01-01-2022 | name 1 |
| 1 | blue | name 2 | 150 | 03-02-2022 | name 1 |
| 2 | blue | name 3 | 100 | 10-05-2023 | name 3 |
| 1 | red | name 4 | 80 | 10-05-2023 | name 1 |
| 2 | white | name 1 | 100 | 12-06-2023 | name 3 |
| 3 | red | name 1 | 120 | 03-02-2022 | name 1 |
| 3 | red | name 1 | 60 | 03-03-2022 | name 1 |

Could you help me please with sql-request via postgresql.
So I need to add column "fist_division_name". It's a division name for a specific user in a specific company for the first sale. This user may have several sales in several companies and in different divisions. I need to find the division that was the first

Comment: Look at `first_value()` analytic function. Please show what you've tried to far and why it's not working.

Comment: "I need to add column" you already have the column in your table? "for the first sale" what do you mean? "I need to find the division that was the first" I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: @Stu, thanks for help 
I used this window function 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_id, company ORDER BY sale_date) AS rn

Comment: @Mephisto, it was example...like output after my sql-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subquery for fetching division_name:

```
select sales.*, 
  (select division_name from sales s2 where s2.user_id = sales.user_id
     ORDER by sale_date limit 1)
  from sales;
```

But using `first_value()` function (as Stu wrote) is the best solution:

```
select sales.*, FIRST_VALUE(division_name) 
  over (PARTITION BY user_id order by sale_date) from sales;
```

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-first_value-function/

Comment: If the above resolved your issue then kindly accept the answer. This helps future questioners with the same issue and it removes the question from the unanswered queue. Please do not leave successfully answered questions ad unanswered.